# Replace contained element text on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, mouseover

I was just take a look at the answer by one user to question regarding switching out content over mouseover. The answer I am referring to is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3088819/532645

What I am trying to figure out is how to adapt the code below so that when a user hover over ANY area of the associating LI element only some specified text changes.

In this case you can see I am trying to trigger a replacement of the H3 text when a user hovers over the LI element which contains that H3 tag.

Any ideas which quickly solve this correct? Code is as follows...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {
  $(".homepage-content-columns li h3").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).attr('small',$(this).html());
      $(this).html($(this).attr('full'));
    },
    function () {
       $(this).html($(this).attr('small'));
    }
  );
});
</script>

<ul class="homepage-content-columns">
  <li class="blue spacer">
    <a href="#a">
    <h3 full="Switch Text A">Text A</h3>
    <p>some text here</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="green spacer">
    <a href="#b">
    <h3 full="Switch Text B">Text B</h3>
    <p>some text here</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="orange">
    <a href="#c">
    <h3 full="Switch Text C">Text C</h3>
    <p>some text here</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the note - resolved that

Comment: if you're storing something like HTML in a non-standard HTML attribute, you may want to check out `.data` : http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Small changes.

1.The `hover` event must be changed to the LI element , and not just the h3.
Therefore:
Change:

```
$(".homepage-content-columns li h3").hover(
```

To:

```
$(".homepage-content-columns li").hover(
```

2.Because of that change , `this` "is" the `li` element.
You want to change the H3 that wrapped in it , so you can use:

```
find("h3")
```

For instance:

```
var htitle = $(this).find("H3");
 htitle.html(htitle.attr('full'));
```

**Put it all together:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {
  $(".homepage-content-columns li").hover(
    function () {
    htitle = $(this).find("h3");
      htitle.attr('small',htitle.html());
      htitle.html(htitle.attr('full'));
    },
    function () {
       $(this).find("h3").html($(this).find("h3").attr('small'));
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: would you mind updating your answer by including the full script modified with your suggestions so I can accept your answer? thanks

Comment: Is that answering your question?

Comment: Excellent! accepted as the answer. Only followup question for you relates to understanding if this approach is a good one or if there is a better/more compliant way of achieving theses goals compared to this approach

Comment: It's more logical that way , because the `hover` is on the `li`, and the `h3` is a "child" of that specific `li`.
The only thing I didn't understand is why do you have 2 functions in the hover event?

Comment: just to confirm Ofir - your saying the approach utilized is indeed the correct one and in turn the script modification you posted represents this approach correct? I was just confused because of your mention of the 2 functions there

Comment: There's no 'good' or 'bad' approach. It's just about a "logical" and "easy-to-understand" approach.

Comment: your so darn fast in responding its crazy - your like a bot